# Linear congruential generator - output is all 0s?

Tags: random, scope, fortran, fortran77

I've been trying to make a pretty basic LCG pseudorandom number generator in Fortran 77 to print out 1000 random numbers to a file, but for whatever reason the output is just 1000 0s. The entire code is pretty short so I've combed it over multiple times and tried changing some things around but I can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong. I have a hunch that it could be a scope issue (if such a concept is even useful in Fortran), but that is really unfounded.

```
      PROGRAM RANDOM
      COMMON ISEED, RANDOMNUMBER
      ISEED = 123
      OPEN (UNIT=1,FILE='rand.in',STATUS='UNKNOWN')

      J=1

    7 CALL RANDU(ISEED)
      J=J+1
      WRITE(1,*) RANDOMNUMBER
      IF(J<1000)GOTO 7

      STOP
      END

      SUBROUTINE RANDU(ISEED)
      PARAMETER (IMAX = 2147483647, IMAXINV = 1./IMAX)
      ISEED = ISEED * 65539
      IF(ISEED<0) ISEED = ISEED + IMAX + 1
      RANDOMNUMBER = ISEED * IMAXINV
      RETURN
      END
```

Does anyone have any ideas here? I'm fresh out.

Comment: Use the main fortran tag to make your post more visible. There are many high quality random number generators in Fortran available. Fortran 90 even has an own intrinsic one (unspecified quality) Also, debugging is easier in this century Fortran and scope is certainly an important concept in Fortran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK now to augment the answer by @Jerry101, I have written a modified code. Here, the key problem is that `IMAXINV` is not explicitly declared as `REAL`, so it is interpreted as `INTEGER` (as a result, `IMAXINV = 1.0 / IMAX` becomes always 0 in the original code).  Also, I have removed `ISEED` from the `COMMON` block (because it is passed as an argument) and put another `COMMON` statement in `RANDU` to share variables among routines. With these modifications the program seems to work correctly.

```
      PROGRAM RANDOM
      COMMON RANDOMNUMBER    !<--- ISEED is deleted from here

      ISEED = 123
      J=1

    7 CALL RANDU(ISEED)
      J=J+1
      WRITE(*,*) RANDOMNUMBER       !<--- write to STDOUT for test
      IF (J < 100) GOTO 7
      END

      SUBROUTINE RANDU(ISEED)
      real IMAXINV                   !<--- this is necessary
      COMMON RANDOMNUMBER            !<--- this is also necessary to share variables
      PARAMETER (IMAX = 2147483647, IMAXINV = 1./IMAX)

      ISEED = ISEED * 65539
      IF(ISEED<0) ISEED = ISEED + IMAX + 1
      RANDOMNUMBER = ISEED * IMAXINV
      END
```

As suggested in the other Answer, we could also use `FUNCTION` to return a variable directly. Then we do not need to use `COMMON`, so the code becomes a bit cleaner.

```
      PROGRAM RANDOM
      ISEED = 123
      J=1

 7    RANDOMNUMBER = RANDU(ISEED)
      J=J+1
      WRITE(*,*) RANDOMNUMBER
      IF (J < 100) GOTO 7
      END

      FUNCTION RANDU(ISEED)
      real IMAXINV
      PARAMETER (IMAX = 2147483647, IMAXINV = 1./IMAX)

      ISEED = ISEED * 65539
      IF(ISEED<0) ISEED = ISEED + IMAX + 1
      RANDU = ISEED * IMAXINV                !<--- "RANDU" is the return variable
      END
```

But note that when `FUNCTION` is used, the type of return variable should be declared explicitly in the calling routine if the function name does not conform to the implicit  rule. (In the above code, `RANDU` is not declared explicitly because it is interpreted as `REAL`). So anyway, there are many caveats in the implicit typing rule in Fortran77...

---

Additional notes:

To avoid these pitfalls, I suggest using Fortran >=90 (rather than Fortran77) because it provides many features for preventing such errors. For example, a minimally modified code may look like this:

```
module mymodule
contains

subroutine randu ( istate, ran )
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: IMAX = 2147483647
    real, parameter :: IMAXINV = 1.0 / IMAX
    integer, intent(inout) :: istate
    real,    intent(out)   :: ran

    istate = istate * 65539
    if ( istate < 0 ) istate = istate + IMAX + 1
    ran = istate * IMAXINV
end subroutine

end module

program main
    use mymodule, only: randu
    implicit none
    integer :: j, istate
    real    :: randomnumber

    istate = 123    !! seed for RANDU()

    do j = 1, 99
        call randu ( istate, randomnumber )
        write(*,*) randomnumber
    enddo
end program
```

Here,

- `implicit none` is used to enforce the declaration of all variables explicitly. This is useful to help avoid incorrect typing of variables (such as `IMAXINV` in the Question!).
- The subroutine `RANDU` is contained in a `module` so that the compiler provides explicit interface and many useful checking (in short, `module` is something like a namespace in C++). `module` can also be used to define global variables in a way much safer than `COMMON`.
- I used `do` ... `enddo` construct for looping over `j` rather than incrementing it manually and using `goto`. The former is actually easier to use, and also `goto` tends to make a code often less readable...
- I named the program file as "test.f90" (note the suffix .f90), which allows free-format. Also, it is okay to use lower-case letters for variables.
- [Also, because `iseed` stores the information on the current status of (pseudo) random number generator, it may be better to use some different varaible name (like istate etc?) to remind that its value needs to be kept during calls.]

So if you are interested, please consider using a more modern version of [Fortran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran) (rather than Fortran77) which allows us to write safer and more robust codes :)

Comment: I largely agree with what you say, but the suggestion to use a function for the PRNG just upsets me too much.

Comment: @francescalus Am I doing some risky coding with "function + PRNG" here...? (I would appreciate if you explain the issue in more detail.) [If it is related to the variable "iseed" for storing the current status of PRNG, yes, the name is very misleading.] Also, I will add a comment about DO also (yes, it is a good point :)

Comment: I wouldn't say "risky" (one just has to be aware of various aspects), but it's a style thing.  Changing the value of the argument `iseed` is a massive side effect.  Admittedly, using functions like this is something I'll just have to accept... I'm not against side effects in functions (being pragmatic), but for PRNGs they are too egregious for my liking.

Comment: Hmm.. sorry, I still cannot catch your point... In my understanding, the current status of internal variables in PRNG needs to be stored somewhere. If they are stored in COMMON or in a module, it means that they are global variables, so they become error-prone against (thread) parallel calculation. So I thought it would be better to pass the state variables as arguments, so that a function becomes "pure". For more readability, it may be better to encapsulate all the state variables and associated routines in a type, but it seems a bit too far from the Question...

Comment: Sorry, the above use of "pure" is strange because the function changes the value of the argument. Also, since I have little experience about PRNG (I usually use a routine from Numerical Recipes ;-), so I hope a more detailed answer will be added about potential issues of writing PRNG (if necessary) :)

Comment: [An external resource would be better, rather than my comment-writing here.  I may be able to find a well-written thing by someone else.]  My preferred is `call randu(rand, state)`, say, but beyond that, yes there will be some stateful nature.  The concern with using functions with this state (and the side effect) over subroutines, is the ability to use functions in an expression.  This leads to worry about prohibited side effects and so on.

Comment: I think I have finally got your point... I.e., the point is probably that the code becomes cleaner and easier to understand/maintain when we use a `function` only in the case where all the arguments are kept intact (the ultimate of which is functional programming?), while using a `subroutine` otherwise. I generally follow this guideline, but the above PRNG case looks like something in between a function and subroutine because a function is more convenient for math expressions. [Btw I have updated the Appendix to use a subroutine.]

Comment: I just saw this, and thanks so much. This solved the issue, I didn't realize I had to explicitly declare IMAXINV to be real. I'm still getting the hang of sharing variables in Fortran, as well as exactly how subroutines work. I largely agree with your suggestions to use a more modern language, but unfortunately this is for a scientific computing class and requires the older language.

Comment: @fireballs Even within Fortran77, I guess your compiler will accept `implicit none`, which will definitely make our life easier (because the chance of bug becomes smaller). As for sharing variables among routines, this page might be useful http://iprc.soest.hawaii.edu/users/furue/improve-fortran.html (which explains how to replace `COMMON` by `MODULE`.) For other tutorial stuff, please see http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Tutorials for example.

Answer (score 1):

It's been decades since I've programmed in Fortran, but I'll try to help.

First and foremost, `IMAXINV` is an integer variable since the name starts with an `I` and you didn't declare it to be a float. So the division result will be truncated to the integer value `0`, which explains your zero outputs. In any case your random number generator should stick with integer operations rather than introducing flooding point operations, both for correctness and speed.

Fortran 77 supports functions that return values, yes? That would be cleaner and more modular than storing the subroutine's result in a global variable.

IIRC, `COMMON` statements are for sharing global values between modules, which is a risky thing for the random number generator's private state.

You have a `COMMON` global variable named `ISEED` and a subroutine formal parameter with the same name (unless I mis-remember how Fortran subroutine declarations work). That will confuse things and should be fixed. Having the subroutine update its parameter `ISEED` rather than the global variable will cause it to return the same value each time this loop calls it. That is, unless the formal parameter is a call-by-reference alias to the actual argument -- of the same name in this code. You see, it's confusing.

Do you have a debugger? If so, single stepping through the program and watching the variables will quickly reveal where the program deviates from your expectations.

Comment: I unfortunately do not have a debugger, but your comment has been very helpful so far. I'm afraid I don't see where I have a subroutine parameter named ISEED, unless I've just misunderstood how subroutine parameters are declared. I definitely think its a case of accidentally changing the wrong variable, but I'm not sure how to actually catch it. I did do a test where I printed ISEED to the same file, and it looks like it is properly changing..

Comment: Cool. IIRC, to make a subroutine return a value, assign the value to the variable with the same name as the subroutine. In this case, you'd either need to declare `RANDU` as an integer-returning subroutine or just rename it, e.g. `IRANDOM`.

Comment: *to make a subroutine return a value, assign the value to the variable with the same name as the subroutine*  You really don't know Fortran do you !